# ABI-Compatibilaty when changing Union

Tags: c++, abi

I'm wondering, if adding values to a `union` will break binary-compatibility of my library.

In my public header the following class is defined:

```
class myClass{
public:    
  myClass();
  ~myClass();
  int a;
private:
  int b;
  union data{
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t y;
    uint8_t z;
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to add a `uint8_t w;` to my union. It doesn't change the size of the class though I'd expect it not to break the ABI. But I'm not sure about this.

[KDE's binary-compatibility-policies](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B#The_Do.27s_and_Don.27ts) are not too specific about this (or I'm missing something).

Comment: Looks like you will be breaking ODR: _"One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition  Until all users of your library recompile with the updated definition.

Comment: @RichardCritten binary compatibility exists well outside of the realm of the standard, since by that definition *any* modification would break compatibility.

Comment: @Quentin my think is - if you are in Undefined Behaviour land - is binary comparability still an issue as there can be no guarantees

Comment: @RichardCritten it absolutely is. Nothing is guaranteed *by the C++ standard*, that much is true, but a specific implementation can very well define what the standard left undefined. It is definitely the case with ABIs, although I now notice that OP forgot to mention which one they're using specifically.

Comment: As long as you don't modify the size of the union, you should be fine.

Comment: @AndreiDamian can you link to any source for that please?